# Error training Faster RCNN v2 inception on augmented dataset but not using SSD Mobilenet v1 coco

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, object-detection

I augmented my dataset and trained it on SSD Mobilenet v1 coco using Tensorflow Object Detection API https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection.

I initially got this error:

> ResourceExhaustedError (see above for traceback): OOM when allocating
>   tensor with shape[]24,256,38,38] and type float on
>   /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc

Then I changed the batch size from 24 to 3 and it started training.

Then I started training using Faster RCNN v2 Inception on the same augmented dataset and got this error:

> InvalideArgumentError (see above for traceback): LossTensor is inf or
>   nan. : Tensor had NaN values

Then I changed the batch size from 1 to 32 and get this error:

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): assertion failed:
>   [maximum box coordinate value is larger than 1.100000: ]

How to fix this?

Comment: Please see if this helps.
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/5474

Comment: Hi @SreeraghAR have you used the code that the author is suggesting us to use?  https://github.com/AjayZinngg/random-scripts/blob/master/check_images.py

Comment: @SreeraghAR I tried to use it and got this error: `Checked 353 files and realized 352 errors`

Comment: @SreeraghAR However, I'm sure that some of the images are correct since I already trained on them successfully. I just added augmented images and this happened.

Comment: @SreeraghAR I already removed the images that have errors. And I still get this error. `InvalideArgumentError (see above for traceback): LossTensor is inf or nan. : Tensor had NaN values`